# RSpec returns all objects to be 'nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am new to Rspec. I am writing a test case to cover some action in a model. Here is my rspec code

test_cover_image_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Issue do

  before :each do
    @issue = Issue.joins(:multimedia).uniq.first
    binding.pry
  end

  describe '#release_cover_image' do
    context 'While making an issue open' do
      it 'should make issue cover in S3 accessible' do
        put :update, :id => @issue.id, :issue => @issue.attributes = {:open => '1'}
      end
    end
  end

 end
```

@issue always returns nil. In my debugger also, Issue.all returns an empty array.

Comment: you shouldn't use @ in Rspec. you should use `let`

Comment: That makes kind of sense when you don't create issues in your test database first.

Comment: spickermann can you please make this as answer?  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests usually run in isolation. That means each test needs to set up the objects before running. After the test run common test configurations delete all created data from the test database. That means you need to create your test data before you can use it.

For example like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Issue do
  # pass all attributes to create a valid issue
  let(:issue) { Issue.create(title: 'Foo Bar') }

  describe '#release_cover_image' do
    context 'While making an issue open' do
      it 'should make issue cover in S3 accessible' do
        put :update, id: issue.id, issue: { open: '1' }

        expect(issue.reload.open).to eq('1')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you have to populate the test database first.

Check out [factory_girl gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) - it is most often used for easy generating test data.

So (general idea is that) you will have to create few factories:

- issues_factory.rb
- multimedia_factory.rb

And use them, to generate the `issue` object prior the test run.

If you're not going to use factory_girl then anyway you should change from creating an `issue` in `before` block to using [`let`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let):

```
let(:issue) { Issue.create }
```